# linux subsystem on windows, how to set working directory to a folder on windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-prompt, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-machine

I am trying to import a file on windows 11 to a linux subsystem (Ubuntu 22.04.1) while it is connected to docker. I am new to this so I am sorry if I am making obvious mistakes. To my understanding (I am following this tutorial: https://degauss.org/using_degauss.html), I need docker running first and then open my linux subsystem. However once I get to `cd` then it gives me the following error: `-bash: cd: too many arguments`. What I need to do is set the working directory to a specific folder so I can proceed with the next step.

typing `pwd` simply showed me that I am in `home\(username I created when installing the linux subsystem)`

I am new to linux and docker so an easy to understand answer is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

I have tried `cd` and then name of path for example `E:\Users\Name\Desktop\folder one\folder two\folder where file is` and I got `-bash: cd: too many arguments`. I also changed \ to / and got the same error. I thought it would set the working directory (folder where file is).

Docker is connected to linux subsystem as I did the hello-world test successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux does not know about drives, there are only directories. Generally, a WSL mounts windows drives, which means you can find them under `/mnt`: generally you should have `/mnt/c` for your `C:\`-drive, please check if you can access `/mnt/e` for accessing your `E:\`-drive.

Your directory should be accessible from:

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/Name/Desktop/"folder one"/"folder two"
```

Good luck

Comment: hi @Dominique, I just tried your answer and it did not work, I got `-bash: cd: No such file or directory` and `-bash: cd: too many arguments`. Any suggestions?

Comment: `No such file or directory` means that your command is correct, but you have made a typo somewhere. What is the exact name of your directory?

Comment: hi @Dominique where the file I am trying to import? that would be within a third folder (sorry I forgot to mention that as I thought it was within a second folder). `pwd` gives me `home/username I created`, the directory where the file is: `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\folder one\folder two\folder where file is`

Comment: What's the content of the `/mnt` directory?

Comment: I just retried the code, it is working? now I get `>` when I entered what you told me in the answer, I am sorry for this question but I am completly new to linux, what happens after this?

Comment: Launching `pwd`, you should be able to see in which directory you're located now. The `>` you see most probably is the prompt "title". You can alter this by typing `PS1="$PWD >`, this will temporarily change your prompt, showing your current directory in the prompt "title".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250194/discussion-between-ineedhelp-and-dominique).

Comment: hi @Dominique, I am not sure why it was not working earlier today. Now it is. thank you so much!